# Como abrir uma pasta no android

Tags: android

Queria abrir um diretorio no android, tentei assim:

```
 public void openFolder()
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/Pictures/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
    }
```

Mas aparece na hora de chamar
" impossivel encontrar aplicação para executar essa ação"

Queria apenas abrir o diretorio

Comment: Seu objetivo é selecionar algum arquivo que sua aplicação vai usar?

Comment: meu objetivo é abrir normalmente a pasta com todos os arquivos, a aplicação nao vai ultilizar.

Comment: O problema é que nem todos têm um gerenciador de arquivos instalado. O que acontece se você trocar `text/csv` por `*/*`?

Comment: aparece pra escolher Contatos, fotos, e galeria, mas eu quero minha pasta

Comment: Acredito que sem um gerenciador de arquivos instalado você não vai conseguir abrir e navegar o diretório. Seria viável pra você criar uma Activity pra listar o conteúdo do diretório? Acho que seria sua única opção.

Comment: mas eu preciso abrir, e excluir os arquivos, se isso for possivel da certo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20430/discussion-between-war-lock-and-andre-ribeiro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Esta pasta existe?

2 - Tem essas permissões? 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

3 - Você está utilizando um AVD ou Dispositivo físico para rodar a aplicação?

4 - Em ambos citados acima, seja qual for a sua resposta, há um programa como: solid explorer, root explorer?

5 - Isto era para funcionar:

```
public void openFolder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/Pictures/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Abrindo pasta"));
}
```

Um  MIME tipo  `"*/*"` no lugar de `"text/csv"`, também resolveria.

Comment: Desta forma ele abre, para retornar para aplicação com o arquivo, e eu nao quero, eu quero que simplesmente abra a pasta e esqueça a aplicação

Comment: Não tem como. Desista! Veja isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843962/view-folder-contents-in-android-using-default-explorer

Comment: eu tenho que criar meu proprio gerenciador? quero apenas listar os arquivos pra poder abrir ou apagar. da pra montar?

Comment: @WarLock, você ta querendo que sua aplicação MANDE uma OUTRA aplicação FAZER DETERMINADA TAREFA. Isso só seria possível se A OUTRA APLICAÇÃO fosse feita somente PARA O QUE VOCÊ QUER: Abrir uma pasta específica.

Comment: Como as coisas não saem como planejamos, aconselho a você revisar o seu projeto e ver uma outra alternativa para isto, exemplo: listar os arquivos do seu diretório, na sua própria aplicação.

Comment: ok, preciso listar, poder abrir, e poder excluir é possivel?

Comment: sim. claro. pode.

Comment: qual arquivo???

Comment: todos os pdf de um diretorio, quando eu for fazer irei criar outros topicos

Comment: @WarLock, você quer listar os pdf somente para leitura através de uma aplicação externa? Você só poderá excluir algo se ela estiver no dispositivo do cliente ou então torna-la "invisível" para visualização. Como pretende disponibilizar esses pdfs? Servidor externo? Download? Como pensou e O QUE JÁ FEZ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20514/discussion-between-rafael-and-war-lock).

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, verifique desta outra forma (veja se funciona).

```
public void abrirDiretorio()
          {
            File pasta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
               + "/Pictures/");
            Uri local = Uri.fromFile(pasta);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(local);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
          }
```

Comment: aparece "o documento nao pode ser anerto porque ele nao é um documento em pdf valido"

Comment: vou separar o caminho para a linha de baixo.